# How to make the holder in if else statements of onClick method work without final in argument Viewholder in arguments of onBindViewHolder method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I am trying to make a text change when a button located along with the text (layoutPasswd) in recycler view and to change it back if the button is again pressed.Like a password hiding button. The values to the adapter is from a static class object as arraylist. The problem occurring now is that the value for all the items (only for layoutPasswd) in recycler view is same.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.layoutUName.setText(users.get(position).getUserName());
    pos = position;
    holder.layoutPasswd.setText("********");
    holder.btnViewChanger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (holder.view1) {
                holder.layoutPasswd.setText(users.get(pos).getPasswd());
                holder.btnViewChanger.setText("hide");
                holder.view1 = false;
            } else {
                holder.layoutPasswd.setText("********");;
                holder.btnViewChanger.setText("Show");
                holder.view1 = true;
            }
        }
      });
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for it to not be final, but used directly in the listener. And it would not make sense to change the value of `holder` in this method. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am trying to make a text change when a button located along with the text (layoutPasswd) in recycler view and to change it back if the button is again pressed.Like a password hiding button. The values to the adapter is from a static class object as arraylist. The problem occurring now is that the value for all the items (only for layoutPasswd) in recycler view is same.

Comment: You need to add a variable to the data class that keeps track of the state of whether the password is shown. The button can change the visibility of the password and also change this value in the data class. And in onBindViewHolder, you use the status of the variable to set whether the password should be visible.

Comment: @Tenfour04 There is already a variable `view1` to keep track of the visibility.

Comment: Anything in the ViewHolder is temporary and will be lost when it scrolls off the screen. For something to be remembered, it has to be stored in your data, and resynced to the views in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: @Tenfour04 could you explain it little more in detail because I am new to this programming and android development. I thought of starting to study android development with a personal project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on the ViewHolders or Views in a RecyclerView to hold any state, because they are recycled. Every time a view scrolls onto the screen, first it calls your `onBindViewHolder` function to update the contents of that ViewHolder to match the data.

Any configuration you set on the views or the ViewHolder instance in `onBindViewHolder` cannot be relied on to stay the same if the view scrolls off the screen, because the original ViewHolder might be recycled to be used for some other data, and when it scrolls back on screen, you might be looking at some other view that has been recycled from other data that just scrolled off the screen.

So if your views have configuration that you want to "stick", you have to back it up when you change it, and restore it in `onBindViewHolder`. The way you accomplish this will depend on how you are managing the data that you pass to the adapter.

If you can modify your User class, you can add a `Boolean` to it that stores whether it should show the password. Then in your `onBindViewHolder`, you restore the state based on this Boolean. And you also update this Boolean when the state changes.

I also updated the way the click listener works to simplify it for toggling. I removed the `pos = position` line, because almost certainly that is not something you should be doing.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User user = users.get(position)
    holder.layoutUName.setText(user.getUserName());
    holder.layoutPasswd.setText(user.isShowPassword() ? user.getPasswd() : "********");
    holder.btnViewChanger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user.setShowPassword(!user.isShowPassword());
            holder.layoutPasswd.setText(user.isShowPassword() ? user.getPasswd() : "********");
            holder.btnViewChanger.setText(user.isShowPassword() ? "hide" : "show");
        }
      });

    // ...
}
```

If you cannot modify the User class, this is more complicated. Then the adapter should have its own `ArrayList<Boolean>` to store the state by position index, but you need to keep this list at least as long as the data that is bound, and reset everything to false if the whole list of data is refreshed.